# Display the dependencies form the pubspec file in an Text Widget or somthing like that

Tags: pubspec.yaml, flutter-pubspec

I need all the dependencies i used for my app, and it would be nice to get them automatically from the pubspec file with the version numbers and display them in an Text widget or somthing like that.

Tools like Package_Info_Plus wont work for this